# How do I get jQuery.validate() to work in ASP.NET with master pages?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-validate

My form contains master page and sub pages ..

How do I validate the form inside the sub pages? When I try with a master page, validation does not run. However, everything works when I do not use a master page.

Please explain how to get jQuery Validate to work in ASP.NET with Master Page.

Comment: The master page is always called first and binds the events to the dom elements even before they are created in the sub pages. So the validation needs to be done in the sub page itself. To reduce your work you can transfer all your validation functions in a new JS file and include it in all your sub pages.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit late, but I thought I would share my findings seeing as I just went through this.

To use jQuery Validation in an ASP.Net Master Page environment, you have to remember that the placeholders change everything including name. Since .validate() relies so heavily on the names of each field, you must get the client side names for each field. As this can change depending on your placeholders (mine end up looking like `name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FirstName"`), your code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                <%= FirstName.Name %>: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 25
                },
                <%= LastName.Name %>: {
                    required: true
                },
                <%= Email1.Name %>: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                <%= Email2.Name %>: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    equalTo: "#<%= Email1.ClientID %>"
                },
                <%= Password1.Name %>: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 7
                },
                <%= Password2.Name %>: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 7,
                    equalTo: "#<%= Password1.ClientID %>"
                }
            },
            messages:{
                <%= FirstName.Name %>: {
                    required: "Please enter your first name.",
                    minlength: $.validator.format("Your first name must be at least {0} characters.")
                },
                <%= LastName.Name %>: {
                    required: "Please enter your last name.",
                    minlength: $.validator.format("Your last name must be at least {0} characters.")
                },
                <%= Email1.Name %>: {
                    required: "Please enter your email address.",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address."
                },
                <%= Email2.Name %>: {
                    required: "Please confirm your email address.",
                    email: "Please confirm with a valid email address.",
                    equalTo: "Email entries do not match."
                },
                <%= Password1.Name %>: {
                    required: "Please enter a password",
                    minlength: $.validator.format("Your password must be at least {0} characters.")
                },
                <%= Password2.Name %>: {
                    required: "Please confirm your password.",
                    equalTo: "Passwords do not match."
                }
            },
            errorClass: "error-label",
            wrapper: "li",
            errorLabelContainer: "#ErrorSection"
        });
    });
```

This code is taken directly from a working web page of mine using [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) version 1.12.0 and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) version 1.11.0.

Edit: I should add that all of the inputs that I am validating are also `runat="server"` for server-side interaction.